# Android app works on android 8 but crashes on android 6

Tags: android, matrix, kotlin, sslhandshakeexception

I am building an app and it is working fine in Android 8

when I test it on older version I get the following crash

- Android Version: 6.0.1
- Device: samsung (SM-J500H)

Crash log

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:319)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.sbs16.ensofia.network.manager.EnsofiaHttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(EnsofiaHttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:46)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.sbs16.ensofia.network.manager.EnsofiaResponseInterceptor.intercept(EnsofiaResponseInterceptor.kt:7)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.sbs16.ensofia.network.manager.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.kt:61)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.sbs16.ensofia.network.manager.ConnectivityInterceptor.intercept(ConnectivityInterceptor.kt:16)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:337)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:643)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
... 41 more
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you request with HTTPS?

Comment: yes I am using https

Comment: This error why, your url haven't got a SSL certifica. Have you got a certifica?

Comment: yes the server has ssl certificate , I am using matrix.org server and we already add in it is configuration the path of ssl certificate file, it is work on android 8 but now when I test on older version I got this error

Comment: Got it, is sertifica self signed or buy licence?

Comment: I do not know, but what is the difference and why this could have different behavior on different android versions?

Comment: It is Google's policy. I answer a code block on down. Can you try it?

Comment: where is the answer that I should try ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a self-signed certificate, Google don't accept this. You should use X.509.

When you request your server, first call the `trustCerts` method as defined below. Then, you can initiate a request.

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void trustCerts() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not trust certs:", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I call this method

Comment: Example, you want to parse a json. You should call when previously for request

Comment: Please consider handling a trycatch statement by logging the exception to some form of logger instead of doing nothing to it unless you're really sure that the catch statement should be ignored.